# JLayer on Raspberry Pi not working

Tags: java, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, jlayer

I try to use Jlayer in my Java project. When I run it on my Windows PC, all works fine. But when I run it on my Raspberry, it doesn't work/ I dont hear anything.
What I tried already:

- I already installed JDK/SE 8
- other sounds, for example, watching a YouTube video, works fine

also I have no errors in the console

thanks

Comment: Note that there is also [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: Am I correct that your Java code runs fine on your Pi and you get no error message? The only thing that bothers you is that you hear **no sound**? Can you create a [mcve] and show it to us? Otherwise it will be hard for us to give you any help, it's a very broad topic.

Comment: @Zabuza My Program: 
https://mega.nz/#!70ZkjLiD!eL-D9gmMXRAq-837g7xwLue_3a-1YG5bSn5TY4sziLA

Comment: @Zabuza Source/my code: 
https://mega.nz/#!79ZyhCDC!JQ0H31J1zdN7P4JY3UJKOScBtRB7ReeRVmOYtletckM

Comment: Please include it in your question by **editing**. And create a **minimal**  example ([mcve]) since your complete program is probably big and contains more than what is relevant for the question.